# Find the plane through (1,2,3)

Tags: vectors

Find the plane through $(1,2,3)$ and parallel to the plane determined by the points $(2,1,-1) ;(1,1,1)$ and $(3,3,0)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vectors $(1,0,-2), (0,0,1)$ are parallel to the plane containing the three points. The cross product of these vectors is $(0,1,0) $ is orthogonal to the plane you want. So the equation is $0(x-1)+1(y-2)+0(z-3)=0$ or $y=2$.